# Not able to connect with mongo from AWS lambda functionin python

Tags: python, mongodb, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have aws lambda which is not able to connect with mongo through VPC.

```
import pymongo

def handler(event, context):
  try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(host="xxxxxxx", port=27017, username=x1, password=x2, authsource="x3, authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
  except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as err:
    print(err)
```

Not able to found the server.

I have created a security group and new roles have given VPC and lambda full access too but not able to connect.

Taken help from https://blog.shikisoft.com/access-mongodb-instance-from-aws-lambda-python/ as well as https://blog.shikisoft.com/running-aws-lambda-in-vpc-accessing-rds/ links.

Please be helpful.
Trying since yesterday but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to help you figured out where the problem is.

**1. Are your MongoDB EC2 Instance and your Lambda hosted on the same VPC?**

- If this the cause of your problem, you should move your services into the same VPC.

**2. Is your Security Group that attached to your MongoDB EC2 Instance**
**and your Lambda has whitelisted/include the default sg?**

- You have to include the **default sg** into your Security Group so, services/instances within that VPC can communicate.

**3. Is your hostname publicly or privately accessed ?**

- If Lambda needs to connect over Internet to access your MongoDB instance, you don't need to attach your Lambda into a VPC.
  Inside a VPC, Lambda requires a NAT Gateway to communicate to open
  world. Try to communicate privately if your MongoDB instance and
  Lambda are in the same VPC.
  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Hope these answers are helpful to you.

Comment: While this answer comprehensively explains the steps needed to debug and resolve the issue, adding the default security group is not needed and might even cause a security concern as usually default security group opens inbound connections on all ports to public. A custom security group allowing inbound connections on only port 27017 (or whichever port on which Mongo listens) from within the VPC would suffice.